# My headset is only considered plugged when I remove it

Tags: motorola-moto-g, headphones, headphone-jack

I have a moto g 4 play and a headset. I can use other headsets with no issue on my phone, and my headset also works properly on other phones (or pc). The issue I'm having is:

When the headset is plugged in the jack, the phone doesn't acknowledge it. When I unplug it the android suddenly recognizes the phone being plugged and unplugged immediately. Some evidences that it is plugged when I remove it are: the volume changes and spotify songs are paused.

I believe it is a software bug, but I cannot assure it. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Experiencing the same on an HTC device since a few weeks. Headset worked fine before with the phone. Other headsets work with the phone and the same headset works fine with other phones.